# Acid-catalyzed hydration of alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

So I'm basically doing an experiment where I measure the effect of pH on the yield of alcohol within the acid catalyzed hydration of ethene. Essentially, all other details aside, I get a mixture of ethanol and ethyl chloride solutions at the end of my experiment. I want to find the total amount of either. I want to use a simple method to determine the amount of each in the solution. I want to avoid using fractional distillation, if possible. I need help to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that there are no other halogenated byproducts or reagents remaining in your solution, and that any levels of bromine and iodine would be negligible compared to chlorine (fluorine would not be detected), then one of the total halogen analysis (TX) methods would be a good choice.

If this is an ongoing analysis that you need to set up, I suggest the *Carius halogen method*. Wikipedia gives a good overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carius_halogen_method):

> The Carius halogen method in analytical chemistry is a method for the
>   quantitative determination of halogens in chemical substances. A
>   known mass of an organic compound is heated with fuming nitric acid in
>   the presence of silver nitrate contained in a hard glass tube known as
>   carius tube, in a furnace. Carbon and hydrogen present in the compound
>   are oxidised to carbon dioxide and water. The halogen present forms
>   the corresponding silver halide (AgX). It is filtered, washed, dried
>   and weighed.

Alternatively, depending on the equipment available to you, you could also do an oxygen bomb combustion of the sample with a bicarbonate absorbant, followed by either titration of the resulting chloride or ion chromatographic (IC) analysis. In the case of the IC finish, you can usually just use the IC eluent as the adsorbant.

If you are only going to do this analysis once, or only rarely, then I would strongly suggest a commercial TX anaysis using *Standard Methods - For the Examination of Water and Wastewater, Method 9020*. [Method 9020B](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2015-12/documents/9020b.pdf) is for the analysis of total organic halogens (TOX) in water, which is not appropriate for your analysis as a whole because it includes a step for extracting trace amounts of organics from water onto activated carbon. But, then a TX analysis is performed on the activated carbon, which is what you would want to do for your compound rather than for the activated carbon. This is typically about an $80 analysis.

Regardless of the TX technique used, you would of course then assume that all of the halogen came from the ethyl chloride and calculate the ethyl chloride concentration from there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The carius method seems to require equipment that my school lab might not have. In particular, the carius tube and the furnace, though I am wondering if I can still do the same analysis without these apparatus. Suppose now that my solution also contained alcohol within it. In particular, I'm extremely sure that the alcohol present is only going to be ethyl alcohol. Is there any test that I can do to find the amount of ethanol in it? Thanks so much once again.

Comment: Do you have access to either gas or liquid chromatography equipment?

Comment: There really isn't a simple, non-instrumental quantitative analysis for alcohols. Going back to the commercial route, if you can assume the only O in your product is from the alcohol, then you could get an O analysis done for about $35-$45. But, if you were to go with that route, there is a combustion/ion selective electrode method for about the same price that would give more accurate results (for the ethyl chloride of course). I think the most likely method you'd be able to do yourself is the bomb combustion followed by gravimetric determination after precipitating Cl- with AgNO3.

Comment: I'm looking for methods which are extremely simple. Like, I was thinking that, since ethyl chloride's hydrogens are barely acidic and ethanol is way more acidic than ethyl chloride, would it not be possible for me to stick a pH probe into the final solution, measure the pH and calculate the yield of ethanol directly using acid-base equilibrium calculations?

Comment: OK, knowing what you do/don't have available is very helpful. Yes a fractional distillation should be a good way to go, with a couple caveats. If you are purely doing it for analytical purposes, and not trying to recover the ethyl chloride, that will be particularly easy. If you have a small distillation apparatus and enough material to sacrifice for the distillation, then you could just weigh the mixture, let the ethyl chloride boil off, then weigh the remaining ethanol. If you want to separate and keep the fractions, remember that ethyl chloride boils at 12C and won't stick around at RT.

Comment: About how many mL of your mixture do you have total? BTW, the pH idea is clever, but without data about the acidity of ethanol in that matrix (and there probably is none) it's just not going to work. Also, do you think that it is mostly ethanol or about what mixture would you guess; 50:50, 70:30, 95:5, etc. If you don't know that, that's fine, but knowing how much total you have would be helpful.

Comment: The acidity of ethanol in that matrix? If I know the pKa of ethanol and if i know how to account for the auto-protolysis of water in my equilibrium calculations, wouldn't that give me the amount of ethanol in the solution?

Also, I don't know what's the proportion of ethanol and ethyl chloride in the solution. However, I know that I will definitely have more than 50 ml of solution for any given experiment. Would that help?

Comment: But you only know the pKa of ethanol in water (~16) or selected other solvents. In DMSO, the pKa of ethanol is more like 30. You just can't predict the pKa of ethanol in an arbitrary solvent, as it's a function of the solvation of both the anion and cation (H+) in that solvent. I tried to think of something clever based on the fact that ethanol is water miscible but ethyl chloride is not, but ethanol would probably solublize the ethyl chloride (that's where I was headed with my how much of each question). I think your distillation idea is probably the best given what you have to work with.

Comment: Oh yea of course. Hmmm but suppose that I had it such that the amount of water is in excess as compared to the amount of ethanol produced in my experiment. Would that allow me to obtain results using the pH method?

Comment: Okay because my experiment basically involves me bubbling ethene into a solution of hydrochoric acid. The pH of each solution varies. I'm basically testing for the relative yield of ethyl chloride and ethanol. I have a few arguments for why one might be formed in a greater amount than the other.

Comment: Essentially, I could argue that because HCl is a strong acid, it will dissociate in water to form a lot of hydronium ions, which will then react with ethene to produce ethyl chloride. So, there'll be very little ethyl chloride formed. However, I could also argue that since HCl is a stronger acid than ethene, it is more likely to react with ethene and produce ethyl chloride. I don't exactly know how good these arguments are, exactly. I'm looking at the relevant mechanisms as well as the equilibrium constants for both reactions to see if I can make conclusions from there.

Comment: I'm more of an analytical type than an organic synthesis jock so I can't help much with that kind of stuff ;) Since your system already contains water from aqueous HCl and is in 1 phase, that shoots my solubility idea. Unless you've taken steps to dry the mixture and remove the HCl that kills my Cl / halogen analysis ideas. I really think pH measurements are a dead end. Distillation looks better all the time. The advantage is the huge difference in boiling points, the disadvantage is the 12C boiling point of EC and how to keep it from evaporating. Even at 0C it'll be gone in a hurry.

Comment: So in the end I should just stick to heating my solution till the ethyl chloride vaporizes and then measuring the mass of that before and after? How long should I heat it for and under what conditions?

Also, thank you so much. I'm not the analytical type, I'm more of the theoretical type in chem and physics so this kind of experimental stuff is beyond me.